# Python Twitch bot !addcom difficulties

Tags: python, twitch

I am making a Twitch bot using Python because mIRC started asking me to pay, so I went with something simpler and free! My current issue is I want to make a command (`!addcom`) where moderators can add commands that other users can use.

For example, `!addcom !test This is a test` would write `!test This is a test` to a file or the Python file itself and then someone could do `!test` and it would say `This is a test` in the chat. Currently I am struggling to find out a good way to do this, and this is what I have so far:

```
def command_addcom():
    file = open("test.txt", "w")
    msg = input('')
    file.write(msg)
    file.close()
    send_message(CHAN,'Command added (testing)')
```

Unfortunately this only asks for input in the command prompt and doesn't help at all. I would love for it to take the text directly from the chat and place it in the file. Sorry that I don't have much code to show, but that is the entire command as it stands! Thanks for the help ahead of time.

Comment: Perhaps you should check the [Twitch API Repo](https://github.com/justintv/Twitch-API). Specifically [here](https://github.com/justintv/Twitch-API/blob/master/IRC.md)

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you save all the user defined the command in a python dict. For instance, in your example, would be

```
command['!test'] = 'This is a test'
```

and for the saving problem you mention, I suggest to use `json` module for it.
to save above **command** dict

```
with file('setting.json','w') as settingFile
    json.dump(command, settingFile)
```

---

Each time the bot init, should load the **command** dict from actual json file

```
with file('setting.json','r') as settingFile:
    command = json.load(settingFile)
```

so you now have the user defined command dict in program

---

Finally, at your parser of user message(here I assume it to be `userMessage`), you should check if the user command could be found in **command** dict. Try

```
userCommand = userMessage.split(' ')[0]
if command[userCommand]:
    # sendmsg to Twicth IRC
    print command[userCommand]
```

the official python document should give enough information about how to use `json` module, or maybe you could try the `ConfigParser` either.